# How to extract specific keys from nested JSON?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse nested JSON data, but having difficulty getting the text from the heavily nested data

```
resp = platform.get('/restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log', params)
print ((resp.text()))

cursor = mydb.cursor()

json_obj = json.loads((resp.text()))
for result in json_obj["records"]:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO calldata (sessionID, startTime, fromName) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                        (result["sessionId"], 
                         result["startTime"], 
                         result["from"]["name"]))
```

JSON Output

```
{
  "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=2",
  "records" : [ {
    "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log/123456?view=Simple",
    "id" : "123456",
    "sessionId" : "123456",
    "startTime" : "2019-10-09T20:47:26.577Z",
    "duration" : 45,
    "type" : "Voice",
    "direction" : "Outbound",
    "action" : "VoIP Call",
    "result" : "Call connected",
    "to" : {
      "phoneNumber" : "123456"
    },
    "from" : {
      "name" : "Jane Doe",
      "phoneNumber" : "123456",
      "extensionId" : "123456"
    },
    "recording" : {
      "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/recording/123456",
      "id" : "123456",
      "type" : "Automatic",
      "contentUri" : "https://media.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/recording/581514130067/content"
    },
    "extension" : {
      "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/extension/1409182064",
      "id" : 123456
    }
  }, {
    "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log/123456?view=Simple",
    "id" : "123456",
    "sessionId" : "123456",
    "startTime" : "2019-10-09T20:37:49.540Z",
    "duration" : 7,
    "type" : "Voice",
    "direction" : "Inbound",
    "action" : "Phone Call",
    "result" : "Missed",
    "to" : {
      "phoneNumber" : "123456"
    },
    "from" : {
      "name" : "Bob Smith",
      "phoneNumber" : "123456"
    }
  } ],
  "paging" : {
    "page" : 1,
    "perPage" : 2,
    "pageStart" : 0,
    "pageEnd" : 1
  },
  "navigation" : {
    "nextPage" : {
      "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=2&perPage=2"
    },
    "firstPage" : {
      "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=2"
    },
    "lastPage" : {
      "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=2"
    }
  }
}
```

The error I get is

> `(result["sessionId"], result["startTime"], result["result"],
>   result["direction"], result["duration"], result["from"]["name"]))
>   KeyError: 'name'`

I'm trying to get the data in the "from" dictionary as well as "records".

Comment: add `print(result['from'])` after `for result in json_obj["records"]:` and check result

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the structure of your JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "uri": "",
    "records": [
        {
            [...]
            "from": {
                "name": ""
            }
        },
        {
            [...]
        }
    ]
}
```

So if you want to acces `result["from"]["name"]` you're not actually getting to it. First you have `records` -> then `from` -> then `name`. And records is by the way an array, so you wouldn't do `results['records']['from']['name']`

If you want to parse your JSON, you can do it like this:

```py
# Reading JSON section
import json

json_dict = json.load(open("a.json", "r"))
# Iterating over records
for record in json_dict["records"]:
    print(record["from"]["name"])
```

Output:

```sh
$ python test.py                                                                                                        
Jane Doe
Bob Smith
```

Comment: Great, that works but I need to insert that into the MySQL database, so It needs to be included in the INSERT INTO part. Right now it just prints it.

Comment: I know, but I can't test it, since I don't have the setup. Just change print statement to `cursor.execute()` calls, you have proper strings from the JSON now

Comment: Gotcha, one more question, sometimes a 'from name' will not exist when this happens I get a keyerror and the script will fail. How can I skip over this without interrupting the script.

Comment: You can check is a key exists in a dictionary -> `if "from" in json_dict`

Comment: I need to skip it though, so if phoneNumber doesnt exist I dont want the script to stop with a keyerror message i just need to ignore it

Comment: So you can skip it. If you check that the key doesn't exist in a dict, you don't jump into `if` branch and do not execute the inserting to database

Answer (score 0):

### Use [`pandas.io.json.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html#pandas-io-json-json-normalize):

- This will give you everything in `json_obj`
- Create a dataframe for the top keys, but `records` won't be expanded
- Create a dataframe for `records` that contains the top level `uri`
- Use `pd.merge` on the two dataframes

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df_top = json_normalize(json_obj)

# drop the unexpanded records column
df_top.drop(columns='records', inplace=True)

df_rec = json_normalize(data, 'records', ['uri'], meta_prefix='top')

df_merged = pd.merge(df_rec, df_top, left_on='topuri', right_on='uri')

# drop and rename columns
df_m.drop(columns='topuri', inplace=True)
df_m.rename(columns={'uri_x': 'records.uri', 'uri_y': 'top.uri'}, inplace=True)

# df_merged view
                                                                              records.uri      id sessionId                 startTime  duration   type direction      action          result to.phoneNumber  from.name from.phoneNumber from.extensionId                                                                  recording.uri recording.id recording.type                                                                      recording.contentUri                                                                      extension.uri  extension.id                                                                                                                                                                    top.uri  paging.page  paging.perPage  paging.pageStart  paging.pageEnd                                                                                                                                                    navigation.nextPage.uri                                                                                                                                                   navigation.firstPage.uri                                                                                                                                                    navigation.lastPage.uri
 https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log/123456?view=Simple  123456    123456  2019-10-09T20:47:26.577Z        45  Voice  Outbound   VoIP Call  Call connected         123456   Jane Doe           123456           123456  https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/recording/123456       123456      Automatic  https://media.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/recording/581514130067/content  https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/extension/1409182064      123456.0  https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=2            1               2                 0               1  https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=2&perPage=2  https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=2  https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=2
 https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log/123456?view=Simple  123456    123456  2019-10-09T20:37:49.540Z         7  Voice   Inbound  Phone Call          Missed         123456  Bob Smith           123456              NaN                                                                            NaN          NaN            NaN                                                                                       NaN                                                                                NaN           NaN  https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=2            1               2                 0               1  https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=2&perPage=2  https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=2  https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2019-10-09T16:00:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=2
```

- `uri_x` is the uri from records and renamed to `records.uri`
- `uri_y` & `topuri` are both the top level `uri`, which were retained from merging

  - Drop `topuri` and rename `uri_y` to `top.uri`
- Drop or rename any other columns as needed or create a separate dataframe with only the required columns
- To save, use `df.to_csv` or a number of other [output options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html).

### Note:

- If you only want `records` (`from` is in records), then you only need the following dataframe `df_rec = json_normalize(data, 'records')` and you don't need to merge.